# little bit confusion in object reference in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple question but i am confused so asking.
What is difference between these two scenarios.

1)

```
DataSet ds = getUsers();
```

2)

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = getUsers();
```

Comment: In the second one, you unnecessarily create an empty `DataSet`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In version 1 here's what happens:

1. `getUsers` creates a new `DataSet` object.
2. The reference gets stored in `ds`.

In version 2 here's what happens:

1. a new `DataSet` object is instantiated and the reference to it is stored in `ds`.
2. `getUsers` creates a *different* `DataSet` object.
3. The reference to this new `DataSet` gets stored in `ds`.
4. The old `DataSet` now no longer has any variables referencing it and will be picked up by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 4):

Version (2) creates a new DataSet then hands it over to be garbage collected. Aside from that, they are the same.

Comment: so first one is optimized way ?

Comment: Not sure if "optimized" is quite the right word, but yes, (1) is the better choice as the new DataSet() line in (2) serves no useful purpose.

Comment: @Reed Copsey, thanks, that was what I was trying to say. You put it more succinctly! :)

Comment: thanx for short and simple explaination.

Comment: @ReedCopsey The first?

Comment: @ispiro Should have been teh second ;)